# Synonymise [url-shortener] and [shorten-url]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tag [url-shortener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-shortener) has 282 questions and 4 followers, but there's also a [shorten-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shorten-url) tag with 16 questions and 0 followers. About half of the questions tagged with [shorten-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shorten-url) are also tagged with [url-shortener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-shortener). I suggest these tags be synonymised (or the least-used tag be burninated).

BTW, there is also a tag [google-url-shortener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-url-shortener), but I think it's logical to have this as a separate tag.

Comment: Came across the same idea today. And this should probably be considered. Either just edit all the questions with [shorten-url] to [url-shortener]  or as you suggested synonymise them

Comment: There wasn't even 1 new question asked in [shorten-url] tag in the past 3 years...

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks for taking care of it.